How to convert integer arithmetic operations to boolean operations using bit-blasting?
For example, I have a simple function:
int4_t add(int4_t a, int4_t b) {
    return a + b;
}

I need to eliminate integer arithmetic operations and use boolean operations instead (A.K.A., bit-blasting).
int4_t add(int4_t a, int4_t b) {
    // Extract individual bits of a and b
    bool a0 = a & 1;
    bool a1 = (a >> 1) & 1;
    bool a2 = (a >> 2) & 1;
    bool a3 = (a >> 3) & 1;

    bool b0 = b & 1;
    bool b1 = (b >> 1) & 1;
    bool b2 = (b >> 2) & 1;
    bool b3 = (b >> 3) & 1;

    // Compute sum and carry for each bit using full adder logic
    bool s0 = a0 ^ b0;
    bool c1 = a0 & b0;

    bool s1 = a1 ^ b1 ^ c1;
    bool c2 = (a1 & b1) | (a1 & c1) | (b1 & c1);

    bool s2 = a2 ^ b2 ^ c2;
    bool c3 = (a2 & b2) | (a2 & c2) | (b2 & c2);

    bool s3 = a3 ^ b3 ^ c3;
    bool c4 = (a3 & b3) | (a3 & c3) | (b3 & c3);

    // Reassemble the result
    int4_t result = (s0) | (s1 << 1) | (s2 << 2) | (s3 << 3);

    return result;
}

A possible way I can think is to implement "soft circuits" in C/C++, including full-adders for addition ops and multipliers for multiplication ops.
However I want to utilize existing tools, like Z3:
from z3 import *

x1 = BitVec('x1', 4)
x2 = BitVec('x2', 4)
out = BitVec('out', 4)

g = Goal()

bitmap = {}
for i in range(4):
    mask = BitVecSort(4).cast(math.pow(2,i))

    bitmap[(x1,i)] = Bool('x1#'+str(i))
    g.add(bitmap[(x1,i)] == ((x1 & mask) == mask))

    bitmap[(x2,i)] = Bool('x2#'+str(i))
    g.add(bitmap[(x2,i)] == ((x2 & mask) == mask))

    bitmap[(out,i)] = Bool('out#'+str(i))
    g.add(bitmap[(out,i)] == ((out & mask) == mask))

g.add(x1 + x2 == out)

simplify = Then('simplify','bit-blast','simplify')
final = simplify(g)

print(final.sexpr())

This will give simplified bit-blasted constriants, where I can recover a new program:
(goals
(goal
  (= k!0 |x1#0|)
  (= k!4 |x2#0|)
  (= k!8 |out#0|)
  (= k!1 |x1#1|)
  (= k!5 |x2#1|)
  (= k!9 |out#1|)
  (= k!2 |x1#2|)
  (= k!6 |x2#2|)
  (= k!10 |out#2|)
  (= k!3 |x1#3|)
  (= k!7 |x2#3|)
  (= k!11 |out#3|)
  (let ((a!1 (= k!1 (= k!5 (or (not k!0) (not k!4))))))
    (not (= a!1 k!9)))
  (let ((a!1 (or (not (or (not k!1) (not k!5)))
                 (not (or (not k!4) (not k!1) (not k!0)))
                 (not (or (not k!4) (not k!5) (not k!0))))))
    (= (= k!2 (= k!6 a!1)) k!10))
  (let ((a!1 (or (not (or (not k!1) (not k!5)))
                 (not (or (not k!4) (not k!1) (not k!0)))
                 (not (or (not k!4) (not k!5) (not k!0))))))
  (let ((a!2 (or (not (or (not k!2) (not k!6)))
                 (not (or (not k!2) (not a!1)))
                 (not (or (not k!6) (not a!1))))))
    (= (= k!3 (= k!7 a!2)) k!11)))
  (not (= (= k!0 k!4) k!8)))
)

But this is kind of dirty, right? Since we need to generate a C/C++ program from the output of the Z3 solver. Which is trivial.
So I am wondering what is the better way to do this.
Edit:
I must convert them into boolean variables, so I cannot use something like bitset. The process to extract each bit in an integer may be improved, and the int4_t type may not exist, but this are not closely related to the core problem :)
My question is mainly about "how to do bit-blasting correctly".
Edit:
This NOT aim to "improve" something like performance, but rather generate a new program under a certain specification for future purposes.

How to convert a C function -- Please tag either c or c++, not both.

There is no magical tool for this. But you could do different tricks. there are tools to convert C code to HDL, for example. Then you can synthesize that HDL which will result in optimized RTL, from which you could get gate-level representation.

Whenever you find yourself with variables with sequential names like a1, a2, etc. you should be using an array. Then you can loop over the array instead of repeating the same code.

// Extract individual bits of a and b -- The reason why you should tag the actual language you are using is that this: // Extract individual bits of a and b exists in C++ by using  std::bitset<4> a, b; (assuming that int4_t is really an integer that has a max value of 31).  There is no need to define 4 separate bool variables.

Even if an interesting exercise, the falsify to all this is that a >> 1 and !a are really arithmetic operations: arithmetic right shift and not equal to 0.

@chux There's no !a in their code, so that's not really relevant. If they needed inversion, they'd presumably use ~a.

I am NOT expecting to see "optimized performance". Instead, this is a required process for future uses.
